# Что конкретно делает компилятор C# при установке опции /optimize

Tags: .net

Какие именно действия по оптимизации кода выполняются? Есть ли в таком случае разница при построении проекта с конфигурацией Debug и Release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В компилятора очень много разных эвристик для оптимизации кода. Он ищет определенные паттерны в коде, и отпимизирует конечный IL код. В качестве простого примера, могу продемонстрировать такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    int y = 200;
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    return;
}
```

Если скомпилировать в `Debug/Release` без оптимизации (я компилировал для `Framework 4.7`), получается такой IL-код:

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 x,
    [1] int32 y
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 100
IL_0003: stloc.0
IL_0004: ldloc.0
IL_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_000a: nop
IL_000b: ldc.i4 200
IL_0010: stloc.1
IL_0011: ldloc.1
IL_0012: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0017: nop
IL_0018: br.s IL_001a

IL_001a: ret
```

В коде лишние `nop`-ы (они сделаны для удобства, что бы ставить брейкпоинты). Переменные сохранены, в конце бесполезный `jump` (`br.s` - безусловный переход), который соответствует бесполезному `return` в `C#` коде.

При компиляции в Debug с оптимизацией, получается такое:

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 x,
    [1] int32 y
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 100
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: ldloc.0
IL_0004: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0009: ldc.i4 200
IL_000e: stloc.1
IL_000f: ldloc.1
IL_0010: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0015: ret
```

'nop'-ов нет, `jump` убран. Видно уже некоторые оптимизации, хоть и небольшие.

При компиляции в `Release` с оптимизацией компилятор применяет все эвристики, и получается такой код:

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.s 100
IL_0002: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0007: ldc.i4 200
IL_000c: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0011: ret
```

Больше никаких локальных переменных (которые отнимают 8 байт со стека), никаких `nop`, и никаких `jump`, которые ничего не делают.

Еще один пример, код `bool b = 1 == 2;` без оптимизации действительно сравнивает 2 числа, но в `Release` и с оптимизациями это будет просто `bool b = false;`.

Оптимизаций очень много, и с каждой новой версией компилятора добавляют новые.

Comment: Вот на счёт nop'ов. В оптимизированном коде их нет, но и для оптимизированного кода я могу расставлять точки останова. Зачем тогда они вообще нужны, если и без них всё работает?

Comment: @D.Stark вы можете их ставить, только не во всех местах. Что создает определенные неудобства. Попробуйте поставить на операторную скобку в начале метода в `Debug+Optimize` (в моем примере). Этот брейкпоинт не сработает. В `Release+Optimize` брейкпоинт не ставится даже `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: [Подскажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873724/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-securitypermissionflag-skipverification)

Comment: @D.Stark я не работал с этим, не могу подсказать