# Зачем нужен SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification?

Tags: .net, компиляция

Зачем существует атрибут `SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification` если у компилятора существует опция /unsafe, которая и так указывает, что сборка содержит небезопасный код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это разные вещи. Параметр `/unsafe` указывает компилятору, что не нужно выдавать ошибку при наличии в коде unsafe-методов, а также что нужно добавить атрибут `SecurityPermissionAttribute (Action = RequestMinimum,  Flags = SkipVerification)` к сборке и атрибут `System.Security.UnverifiableCodeAttribute` ко всем ее модулям. Флаг `SkipVerification` CLR использует во время выполнения для определения, нужно ли бросать VerificationException при попытке выполнить код, не проходящий верификацию (который может быть получен, помимо ключевого слова unsafe, при написании кода на С++/CLI или при использовании средств динамической генерации кода из System.Reflection.Emit).